# html2canvas and React to generate pdf doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm using html2canvas and jsPdf to generate Pdf from HTML for one react application.

onClick of my download button I call this function :

```
printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToOfferInfo');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    if (pdf) {
      html2canvas(input, {
        useCORS: true
      })
        .then(canvas => {
          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          console.log(imgData); //Maybe blank, maybe full image, maybe half of image
          pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
          pdf.save('download.pdf');
        });
    }
}
```

The result is totally random. The result of canvas is full, half or blank but not right.

I think that issue is about rendering of React.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: same error like this? RangeError: Invalid code point NaN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternative solution. Instead to use html2canvas lib, we can use [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) lib. It's working with it.

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
...
        printDocument() {
            const input = document.getElementById('divToOfferInfo');
            const pdf = new jsPDF();
            if (pdf) {
              domtoimage.toPng(input)
                .then(imgData => {
                  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                  pdf.save('download.pdf');
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, same code, h2c didn't work, this worked right away.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this. I am using this code and it is working well.

```
savePDF() {

        const printArea = document.getElementById("printWrapper");

        html2canvas(printArea).then(canvas => {
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            const pdf = new jsPDF();

            pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 20, 20, 180, 160);

            pdf.save('saved.pdf')
        })

    }
```

Comment: causing `RangeError: Invalid code point NaN` to me

Comment: Did you check your dataURL? I think this related to your dataURL.

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. I had to print in a landscape mode so the width and height was not playing good.  Calculated height  to play good with width as :  
      const imageWidth = 280;
      const imagHeight = (canvas.height * imageWidth) / canvas.width;
      doc.addImage(dataURL, "JPEG", 10, 60, imageWidth, imagHeight);